# Python - mask multidimensional

Tags: python, numpy, mask

I would like to mask some values of an array. The array is 3D and the mask is 2D.

I want to mask all the coordonates in the direction of `frametemperature_reshape.shape[0]`.

I tried the following loop:

```
for i in range(frametemperature_reshape.shape[0]):
    frames_BPnegl = np.ma.array(frametemperature_reshape[i,:,:], mask=mask2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to create a 3D mask based on replications of the 2D one across the third dimension as follows:

```
mask3 = mask2 * np.ones(3)[:, None, None].
masked_output = np.ma.array(frametemperature_reshape, mask=mask3)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can [broadcast](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) the 2D mask against the 3D array, so that its size is expanded along the 3rd dimension without actually duplicating it in memory:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randn(10, 20, 30)
mask = np.random.randn(10, 20) > 0

# broadcast `mask` along the 3rd dimension to make it the same shape as `x`
_, mask_b = np.broadcast_arrays(x, mask[..., None])

xm  = np.ma.masked_array(x, mask_b)
```

Comment: Nice one -- this is definitely the best way to do it. Hadn’t realised broadcast_arrays existed!

Comment: Yeah, it's not a function I use that often, since you can almost always broadcast implicitly. To be honest, I think the `masked_array` constructor ought to broadcast the mask against the array internally - I might consider making a pull request.

Comment: In this case the more natural function seem to me `mask_b = np.broadcast_to(mask[..., np.newaxis], x)`, as we don't want to broadcast `x` anyway.